# "float: left" div gets pushed down on input focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following form for lyrics upload. I've changed the design of the form a little bit, and now facing a weird problem.

I've created a fake-datalist using JS. On input focus, a fake-datalist (an ul element) is appended next to the input element. Its position is set to absolute so it shouldn't disrupt the flow of the document when it appears. However, it does. I can't seem to identify the problem. Once the datalist appears, the div next to the table gets pushed down. Table width isn't changing when the datalist appears, so it's not squizing the div and pushing it down.

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezdpjg)

```js
var artists = [{"artist":"3 Doors Down"},{"artist":"5 Seconds of Summer"},{"artist":"Adele"},{"artist":"Alicia Keys"},{"artist":"Amanda Abizaid"},{"artist":"Avril Lavigne"}];
var albums = [{"album":"The Better Life","year":"2000","cover":"3_doors_down_2000_the_better_life.jpg"},{"album":"Away from the Sun","year":"2002","cover":"3_doors_down_2002_away_from_the_sun.jpg"},{"album":"Seventeen Days","year":"2005","cover":"3_doors_down_2005_seventeen_days.jpg"},{"album":"3 Doors Down","year":"2008","cover":"3_doors_down_2008_3_doors_down.jpg"},{"album":"Time of My Life","year":"2011","cover":"3_doors_down_2011_time_of_my_life.jpg"}];
var songs = [{"song":"Kryptonite","track_no":"1"},{"song":"Duck and Run","track_no":"3"},{"song":"Be Like That","track_no":"5"},{"song":"So I Need You","track_no":"11"}];

function datalist(element) {
  return new datalist.prototype.init(element);
}
datalist.prototype = {
  init: function(element) {
    if (!element) {
      this.element = document.createElement("ul");
      this.element.classList.add("datalist");;
      this.hide();
    } else {
      this.element = element;
    }
  },
  update: function(queryElement) {
    this.clear();
    var lookUpArray = queryElement.name + "s";
    var results = this.search(window[lookUpArray], queryElement.value, queryElement.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var value = results[i][queryElement.name];
      switch (queryElement.name) {
        case "album":
          li.setAttribute("data-year", results[i].year);
          break;
        case "song":
          li.setAttribute("data-track_no", results[i].track_no);
          break;
      }
      if (queryElement.value != "") {
        var re = new RegExp(queryElement.value, "gi");
        value = value.replace(re, "<span class=\"highlight\">" + "$&" + "</span>");
      }
      li.innerHTML = value;
      this.element.appendChild(li);
    }
    return results.length;
  },
  search: function(lookUpArray, string, queryType) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
      if (lookUpArray[i][queryType].toLowerCase().search(string.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        results.push(lookUpArray[i]);
      }
    }
    return results;
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.element.innerHTML = "";
  },
  hide: function() {
    this.element.style.display = "none";
  },
  show: function() {
    this.element.style.display = "";
  },
  remove: function() {
    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
  },
  for: function(sibling) {
    sibling.parentElement.appendChild(this.element);
    this.hide();
  },
};
datalist.prototype.init.prototype = datalist.prototype;

var lastVisitedInput = null;

$("#lyrics-form").on("focus", "input.datalist-input", function() {
  if (this.parentElement.children.length == 1) {
    this.parentElement.appendChild(datalist().element);
  }
  if (lastVisitedInput) {
    datalist(lastVisitedInput.nextElementSibling).hide();
  }
  lastVisitedInput = this;
  if (datalist(this.nextElementSibling).update(this)) {
    datalist(this.nextElementSibling).show();
  } else {
    datalist(this.nextElementSibling).hide();
  }
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (lastVisitedInput) {
    var exceptions = getExceptions(lastVisitedInput);
    if (!contains(exceptions, e.target)) {
      datalist(lastVisitedInput.nextElementSibling).remove();
      lastVisitedInput = null;
    }
  }
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("input", "input.datalist-input", function() {
  if (datalist(this.nextElementSibling).update(this)) {
    datalist(this.nextElementSibling).show();
  } else {
    datalist(this.nextElementSibling).hide();
  }
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("click", "li", function() {
  this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.value = this.innerText;
  $(this.parentElement.previousElementSibling).trigger("input");
});

function getRecord(input) {
  var lookUpArray = window[input.name + "s"];
  for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
    if (input.value == lookUpArray[i][input.name]) {
      return lookUpArray[i];
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function getExceptions(input) {
  var exceptions = [
    input,
    input.nextElementSibling,
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.nextElementSibling.children.length; i++) {
    exceptions.push(input.nextElementSibling.children[i]);
  }
  return exceptions;
}

function contains(array, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === item) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; } *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }  body { line-height: 1.5; font-family: sans-serif; }   input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; } textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="search"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"] { border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2); padding: 4px; margin: 1px; }   table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
   
body {
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px;
}

#songInput {
  overflow: auto;
}

#songTable td {
  position: relative;
}

#songTable,
#coverDiv {
  float: left;
}

#coverDiv {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#artist,
#album,
#song {
  width: 250px;
}

#artist {
  width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#year,
#track_no {
  width: 70px;
}

#songTable td {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#songTable td:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#songTable .int-input {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#coverDiv > * {
  display: block;
}

#coverDiv img {
  width: 137px;
  height: 137px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin: 1px;
}

#coverUpload {
  margin: 1px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 250px;
}

#lyricsBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#submit {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.datalist {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 1px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 195px;
  width: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.datalist li {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: default;
}

.datalist li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: black;
}

.datalist .highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <form action="addlyrics.php" id="lyrics-form" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="songInput">
      <table id="songTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Artist</td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <input type="search" name="artist" id="artist" class="datalist-input" placeholder="Artist" required />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Album</td>
          <td>
            <input type="search" name="album" id="album" class="datalist-input" placeholder="Album" required />
          </td>
          <td class="int-input">Year</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="year" id="year" class="input-num" placeholder="Year" required />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Song</td>
          <td>
            <input type="search" name="song" id="song" class="datalist-input" placeholder="Name" required />
          </td>
          <td class="int-input">#</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="track_no" id="track_no" class="input-num" placeholder="ID" required />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div id="coverDiv">
        <img src="covers/blank.gif" id="cover" />
        <input type="file" name="cover" id="coverUpload" accept="image/*" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="lyrics" placeholder="Lyrics" id="lyricsBox" /></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: notice that if you have <input type='text'> instead of search then the cover not go left and under this is with dropdown issue or and with class="datalist-input" where you have in the css class="datalist-input"? I can't see it I see only .datalist

Comment: @Grisza Input elements have the `.datalist-input`. The fake-datalist (`ul.datalist`) added programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `overflow: auto;` from `#songInput`, the parent element of the table and the div, solved the problem. Although, I don't understand why `overflow: auto;` on the parent would push the div down. Dynamically added `ul.datalist`'s position is set to absolute, and when it appears, the only thing it might do is extend the height of the table, which shouldn't effect the div at the right.